# VBA - How to grab the cell below if a cell has text?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Basically I have a column of text and I want to move the cell below to the right if a cell has text. This may sound nonsense, so please see image below for the effect that I wanted. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: All the cells have text...

Comment: Most importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your desired "after" representation is going to make it very hard to do. Consider listing `Jerry` twice, with `Blue` and `Black` in their own cells/rows instead. You'll need a loop, some conditions, ..which specific part are you stuck on?

Comment: I second both statements above mine ^.  Every cell has text.  You combined two colors into one cell with Jerry

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is really a not a great question, [as it fails the rules of StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but still, this is some possible answer, producing this output:

[image]

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim currentCell As Range: Set currentCell = Range("D1")
    Dim rangeToWrite As Range: Set rangeToWrite = Columns("D:E")
    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim myRng As Range: Set myRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1))
    Dim stayLeft As Boolean: stayLeft = True
    rangeToWrite.Clear

    For Each myCell In myRng
        If Len(myCell) Then
            If stayLeft Then
                stayLeft = False
                If currentCell.Address <> Range("D1").Address Then
                    Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(1, -1)
                End If
                currentCell = myCell
            Else
                Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(0, 1)
                With rangeToWrite
                    If currentCell.Column > .Columns(.Columns.Count).Column Then
                        Set currentCell = currentCell.Offset(0, -1)
                        currentCell = currentCell & vbCrLf & myCell
                    Else
                        currentCell = myCell
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Else
            stayLeft = True
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

The code is quite "tricky" (or nasty), but it works. And stuff like `rangeToWrite.Columns(rangeToWrite.Columns.Count).Column` can make plenty of the VBA devs out there start hating VBA even more.

What the code does?

- It reads one by one the cells of the first column of the `ActiveSheet`;
- If the cell is empty, it updates `stayLeft` to false. This means that the next value would be written in the left column of the `Range("D:E")`;
- It writes the value either on the left or the right column;
- If there are no spaces it keeps writing all the values to the right column, concatenating with the previous value;

Press <kbd>F8</kbd>, it is easier to see than to explain!

Comment: Thank you very much. I played around with code and is still trying to digest it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I played around with code and is still trying to digest it. If let says the cell below Tommy is blank, the code would not work.  @vityata  Once again, this is my first question here. Again, Thanks

Comment: @YYH -  You are welcome. Just make sure that you follow the rules the next time ☺ If you do so, you would get really good answers.